# How to avoid duplication

Tags: c++, performance, templates, macros, overloading

Consider below functions

```
f(int a[])
{
     ///CODE
     for
      for
       if(a[i] > 0)
       //change i on some condition
     for
        //CODE
        if(a[i] > 0)
    ///CODE

}
f(int a[], int th)
{
     ///CODE
     for
      for
        if(a[i] < th)
       //change i on some condition
     for
        //CODE
        if(a[i] < th)
    ///CODE
}
```

So we have f function with a optimized huge body, 
several lines are the same: if(a[i] > 0)
I want to add extend this function so that if a parameter is added, those lines should change to if(a[i] < th)
When I overload the function, hundreds of line is duplicated (becomes hard to maintain), so i don't want this. Also I cannot divide the body into functions because "the line" appears in too many inner loops.

First idea:

```
f(int a[], int th = -1)
{
     ///CODE
        if(th == -1)
            if(a[i] > 0)...
        else
            if(a[i] < th)...
     ///CODE
}
```

I cannot do this because of the performance overhead of introducing the additional if to the inner loop.
Is there a way to solve it both efficiently and clearly, perhaps using templates or macros?

Comment: Function pointer seems like a good attempt...?

Comment: @CppLearner: cannot do that due to performance constraints. No function call is allowed inside the inner loop.

Comment: On most modern CPUs, an `if` that is correctly predicted and requires no calculation is basically free. Are you guessing about the "performance overhead of introducing the additional if" or have you measured? Keep the code simple and the compiler will optimize it.

Comment: Performance overhead because an if?? Looks quite strange.

Comment: @AlexTheo: The overhead of an `if` can potentially be huge if the pipeline has to be flushed.  But as David Schwartz points out, it can also be close to zero.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth which pipeline?? an if will be translated as asm - cmp the execution of an cmp in asm will take some miliseconds or less micr. What kind of projects do you talking about?? And finally compiler will optimize the code anyway.

Comment: @AlexTheo: The CPU pipeline.  Every time a conditional is mispredicted, the pipeline has to be emptied, which introduces dozens of stall cycles where nothing happens (assuming we're talking about a modern desktop/server processor).

Comment: In a normal user space application it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @AlexTheo: Tight inner loops also exist in user-space code.

Comment: A templated functor will probably get inlined. A function pointer won't be.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth you have so many if's in other part of code, in external libraries, in OS internal routines, in drivers and so on, does it make any sense to optimize this one?? Read any book about software engineering and all of them say the same thing, optimize the code when you really need it and optimize it much more in problematic places, such as loops and algorithms.

Comment: @AlexTheo: If this is an inner loop and profiling has identified it, then this is what you optimise.  Eliminating conditionals in inner loops can help significantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass functions via template arguments:

```
template<bool Cmp(int,int)>
void f(int a[], int th)
{
    //..
    if (Cmp(a[i],th)) {
       //...
    }
    //...
}
```

You can then use `f` like this:

```
bool cmp(int a, int b) { return a < b; }
f<cmp>(...)
```

Comment: And importantly, the function should be inlined by the compiler.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Ahh yes, that's why I refrained from the stl's `less` function. It's more complex (implemented as a functor) and you cannot be sure whether it gets inlined or not. It's best to check assembly though for every compiler used. but usually it works quite good. If not you can use the `inline` keyword or even some compiler specific attributes.

Comment: @krynr: Thank you, it worked! It seems that when we pass functions as template parameters, compiler can inline them.

Answer (score 6):

You could try to make this a function-template that takes an arbitrary predicate. If the predicate is simple, as in your cases, you can probably rely on the compiler to inline it, so there will be no loss of efficiency. You should profile your application to verify that. The code could look like this:

```
template<class Pred>
void f(int a[], Pred pred) {
 ///CODE
 for
  for
   if(pred(a[i]))
   //change i on some condition
 for
    //CODE
    if(pred(a[i]))
///CODE
}
```

Pre-C++11 you'd have to pass functors or function-pointers as predicates, in C++11 you could use lambdas:

```
f(data, [](int val){ return val > 0; });
f(data, [th](int val){ return val < th; });
```

Comment: I like this solution. If the body of the whole function is big, I would say to reduce it, factoring out to the outer loop section happens, so that, primarily, only the section that needs to be templated is.